# Facing error in LeetCode. The error is as follows:

Tags: c, memory-management

Line 9: Char 22: runtime error: store to address 0x7fff41648ec4 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int' [solution.c]
0x7fff41648ec4: note: pointer points here
01 00 00 00 70 60 00 00  c7 4f e5 06 29 7f 00 00  10 90 64 41 ff 7f 00 00  60 95 e8 06 29 7f 00 00
^

Question:
Given an array nums. We define a running sum of an array as runningSum[i] = sum(nums[0]…nums[i]).

Return the running sum of nums.

```
Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [1,3,6,10]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4].
Example 2:

Input: nums = [1,1,1,1,1]
Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+1, 1+1+1, 1+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1].
Example 3:

Input: nums = [3,1,2,10,1]
Output: [3,4,6,16,17]
```

My solution:

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* runningSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){
    if(numsSize>=1){
        returnSize[0]=nums[0];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<numsSize;i++){
        returnSize[i]=returnSize[i-1]+nums[i];
    }
    return returnSize;
}
```

Comment: It is clearly not following the instruction in the `Note`

Comment: If you have an update, [edit] your question. But it doesn't matter, as I said, you have a function specification but you don't follow it. So no wonder the program is crashing, as it tries to `free` something that was not `malloc`ed (as one of the possible reasons)

Comment: Based on the naming `returnSize` is also most likely not an array of the size `numsSize` but instead a pointer to a single `int` which is supposed to hold the size of the returned array

Comment: Is it supposed to be like this:                                                                                       int* runningSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){
    if(numsSize==1){
        *returnSize=*nums;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<numsSize;i++){
        *returnSize=*returnSize+*nums;
    }
    return *returnSize;
}